# Django forms argument of type 'Event' is not iterable

Tags: django, django-forms

Hello I'm designing a registration system for athletes to register for an athletic competition. The registration page captures all of the athlete's information and saves it in a database in an 'athlete' model. Then the athletes email address (which is a unique field in the model) is stored as a session variable and the user is redirected to the payment page. The payment page will get the event information from arguments passed to the page and then pull the athlete's email address from the session variable and use that to get the athlete's information. From there, it queries the database using the athlete and event information to find the cost and present that to the user as a registration fee.

Everything seems to be fine with the registration page, however I get an **"argument of type 'Event' is not iterable"** error when redirecting to the payments page from the registration page.

Here is the view for the payments page.

```
def payment(request, event_year, event_slug):

    event = Event.objects.get(event_date__year = event_year, event_slug = event_slug)

    athlete = Athlete.objects.get(email_address=request.session.get('user_email'))

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PaymentForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            # process form payment data
            form.save()
            return redirect('home')
    else:
        form = PaymentForm(event, athlete)

    return render(request, 'events/event_payment.html', {
        'event': event,
        'athlete': athlete,
        'form': form
    })
```

The payment form and the registration form are both regular forms, and not ModelForms. Here is the template for the payment form. It should be noted that if the {{ form }} tag is removed from the template then the page renders without an error, however I need the {{ form }} to process the payment.

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block head %}
    <title>{{ event.event_date.year }} {{ event.event_name }} Payment</title>
{% endblock head %}

{% block content %}

<div class="row-fluid">
  <div class="span12">
    <h2>{{ event.event_date.year }} {{ event.event_name }} Entry Form for {{ athlete.first_name }} {{ athlete.last_name }}</h2>

    <form action="" method="post">
      {% csrf_token %}

      <p>Payment for {{ athlete.first_name }} {{ athlete.last_name }}

      {{ form }}

      <button type="submit">Register</button>
    </form>

  </div>
</div>

{% endblock content %}
```

For completion's sake here's the relevant parts of the registration page, although I don't think that it matters:

```
def register(request, event_year, event_slug):
event = Event.objects.get(
    event_slug = event_slug,
    event_date__year = event_year
)

if not event:
    raise Http404

if request.method == 'POST':
    form = EntryForm(data=request.POST, event=event)
    if form.is_valid():
        from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist
        try:
            athlete = Athlete.objects.get(email_address=form.cleaned_data['email_address'])
            athlete.first_name = form.cleaned_data['first_name']
            athlete.last_name = form.cleaned_data['last_name']
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            # code to create new athlete object

        request.session['user_email'] = athlete.email_address

        return redirect('payment', event_slug=event_slug, event_year=event_year)
    else:
        form = EntryForm(request.POST)
        return render(request, 'events/event_register.html', {'form': form})

return render(request, 'events/event_register.html', {
    'event': event,
    'form': form
})
```

Here is the full Traceback:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/2014/bikini-figure-fitness-physique-championships/payment

Django Version: 1.5.1
Python Version: 2.7.6
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'events')
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware')


Template error:
In template /home/nse/Development/Django/cbbf/events/templates/events/event_payment.html, error at line 17
   argument of type 'Event' is not iterable
   7 : {% block content %}


   8 : 


   9 :       <!-- Example row of columns -->


   10 :       <div class="row-fluid">


   11 :         <div class="span12">


   12 :           <h2>{{ event.event_date.year }} {{ event.event_name }} Entry Form for {{ athlete.first_name }} {{ athlete.last_name }}</h2>


   13 :           <p></p>


   14 :           <form action="" method="post">


   15 :             {% csrf_token %}


   16 :             <p>Payment for {{ athlete.first_name }} {{ athlete.last_name }}


   17 :              {{ form }} 


   18 :             <button type="submit">Register</button>


   19 :           </form>


   20 :         </div>


   21 :       </div>


   22 : 


   23 : {% endblock content %}


   24 : 

Traceback:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  115.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/home/nse/Development/Django/cbbf/events/views.py" in payment
  164.      'form': form
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/shortcuts/__init__.py" in render
  53.     return HttpResponse(loader.render_to_string(*args, **kwargs),
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/loader.py" in render_to_string
  177.         return t.render(context_instance)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  140.             return self._render(context)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  134.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  830.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  74.             return node.render(context)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  124.         return compiled_parent._render(context)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  134.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  830.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  74.             return node.render(context)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  63.             result = block.nodelist.render(context)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  830.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  74.             return node.render(context)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render
  87.             output = force_text(output)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/encoding.py" in force_text
  99.                 s = s.__unicode__()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in __str__
  100.         return self.as_table()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in as_table
  222.             errors_on_separate_row = False)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in _html_output
  145.         top_errors = self.non_field_errors() # Errors that should be displayed above all fields.
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in non_field_errors
  248.         return self.errors.get(NON_FIELD_ERRORS, self.error_class())
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in _get_errors
  117.             self.full_clean()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in full_clean
  272.         self._clean_fields()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in _clean_fields
  281.             value = field.widget.value_from_datadict(self.data, self.files, self.add_prefix(name))
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/forms/widgets.py" in value_from_datadict
  522.         if name not in data:

Exception Type: TypeError at /2014/bikini-figure-fitness-physique-championships/payment
Exception Value: argument of type 'Event' is not iterable
```

Comment: Can you post the full traceback?

Comment: Yes, I've added the full Traceback

Comment: I think your issue is in PaymentForm(event, athlete)... Have you overridden __init__ to accommodate for passing event and athlete to it?

Comment: Thanks Mario you are correct. I was trying to pass the arguments to the form when it wasn't needed. The arguments only needed to be passed to the view. Please submit an answer so that I can give you credit.